# Virtual PC and network sharing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, virtualization

I am running the Windows 7 RC which prevents me from running my companys VPN software (Juniper Network Connect). So I thought I could use the Virtual PC capability in Windows 7 to do it for me.

I have downloaded and installed the XP VM for the Virtual PC addition to Windows 7.
I can log into my VPN in the XP machine via Network Connect.

What I'd like to be able to do now is bridge/share (?) the VPN connection to the Windows 7 host.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

EDIT
Turns out on Windows 7 RTM, Network Connect seems to work fine all by itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it! If you connect through Network Connect in the XP machine and then run a proxy in there, using the internal network adapters, the host (and other VMs) can see the proxy and will be routed out through NetworkConnect to the VPN!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll be able to pull that off. I've used Juniper Network Connect a little on Windows XP, and while it does create a "virtual NIC", I don't think you'll get away w/ building a "network bridge" inside the virtual  Windows XP PC between the virtual NIC that lets the XP machine talk to the real world and the Juniper "virtual NIC" that the VPN client creates.

I'm seeing some people talking about downloading the "JuniperSetupClientInstaller.exe" file from their VPN server manually on a "supported" OS and then running the installer in Windows XP "compatibility mode" inside of 32-bit Windows 7. You might give that a shot.